# Generic search control

Tags: jquery, search, model-view-controller

I am trying to build a re-usable Product finder control for my MVC application.
A Modal window opens, and the client can enter some text, hit search, and the Products are returned and displayed below the search textbox (via an ajax call).

The issue I have, is I need to return the Product details which the client has selected back to the page which opened the modal window. From my knowledge of MVC, I make a call to a Product Controller, passing the selected Products up as a model, and then call the relevant view (ShowProducts).
This works, but as you can imagine, the partial view for searching is hard wired to talk to a certain controller, and also return to the same view.

Using MVC, I imagined the client could add a "callback" View) into a model passed into the Search screen, and that could be passed up the controller, which would then use that value to return the correct view.
It seems a little strange having to to wire things up like this, so the next part of this question, is whether there is an easier / more sensible approach.

Would it be possible to do something like this, using client side programming:

Before modal window is opened, the caller page registers with an event,
Search control raises an event, passing in the Product details
Caller page receives the data (I am assuming it would receive a table containing the Product details) and adds it to a list somehow.

I appreciate this is quite vague, but I am trying to understand if something like this is actually do-able (I have saw simple examples, where a textbox might be changed in such a way, but not passing, essentially full models around in the client side)

Any help / guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I think I don't understand you properly, or I cannot figure out what exactly you want. You Load a search view on modal window, let the user search and show the results of the search in the modal window. Then you can select several products and show the selected products details in somewhere (where?). You had the ajax and the actions made, but what do you need. Could you please especify your actual exactly process and your desired exactly process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I will try to make the problem clearer.

User clicks a button on the Index page, and a Modal window will open
Modal window will allow user to search for products (it is submitted via a button)
All criteria matching search string is returned to Modal View, and displayed below the search area.
User cna then select a Product, which will then close the modal, and the selected product will appear on a list on Index page.

Hopefully this makes sense.

I have tried using knockout MVC and various javascript examples, but they are not working as expected.

Comment: The whole process makes sense to me, and is completly "do-able". But I don't know yet what "part" of that process you cannot do or what process you need guidance to achieve it. As far I know, you actually make the filter via ajax without troubles, so I cannot understand why you cannot load (also via ajax) the product details in the "main" view after closing modal window.

Comment: Seems I am not describing the problem too well (maybe because there are a number of things I am struggling with). As it happens, I have started learning KnockoutJS which appears to help me with the problems I have (mainly taking data from my modal, and sending it back to the caller without a server round trip).

Comment: Well, we start to understand each other ;) The last sentence of your comment it's the key "without server round trip" since i don't know your markup I'll put an answer with a simple example and let's see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit dirty, but an example:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkwwwvu2/)

HTML:

```
<div id="list_result">
    LIST OUTPUT:
    <ul id='selection_list'></ul>
</div>
<button id="modal_button">OPEN MODAL DIALOG</button>
<div id="modal_dialog">
    <ul id="product_list">
        <li><input name="product_details_selection" type="checkbox"/>Product 1 Details</li>
        <li><input name="product_details_selection" type="checkbox"/>Product 2 Details</li>
        <li><input name="product_details_selection" type="checkbox"/>Product 3 Details</li>
        <li><input name="product_details_selection" type="checkbox"/>Product 4 Details</li>
        <li><input name="product_details_selection" type="checkbox"/>Product 5 Details</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#modal_button").button().click(function(){
   $("#modal_dialog").dialog({
       autoOpen: true,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            $("#selection_list li").remove();
            $("#product_list li input[name='product_details_selection']:checked").each(function(){
                $("#selection_list").append("<li>"+$(this).parent().text()+"</li>");
                console.log("test");
            });
        }
      }
   });
});
```